# Get combined row from multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a main table and some sub-tables that contain at least 1 column from the main table. Sub-tables are updates of some part of main table. I would like to get updated row of main table at a specific date.

```
Main table:

table1
| id | colA | colB | colC | colD | colE | createDate  |
|:---|:----:|:----:|:----:|:----:|:----:|:-----------:|
| a1 |  1   |  1   |  1   |  1   |  1   |  2017/01/01 |

Sub-tables :

table2
| mainid | colA | colB | createdate  |
|:------:|:----:|:----:|:-----------:|
|   a1   |  2   |  2   |  2018/05/01 |
|   a1   |  3   |  3   |  2019/01/01 |
|   a1   |  4   |  4   |  2020/01/01 |

table3
| mainid | colA | colB | colC | createDate  |
|:------:|:----:|:----:|:----:|:-----------:|
|   a1   |  6   |  6   |  6   |  2019/01/01 |
|   a1   |  7   |  7   |  7   |  2020/01/01 |
|   a1   |  8   |  8   |  8   |  2021/01/01 |

table4
| mainid | colA | colE | colC | createDate  |
|:------:|:----:|:----:|:----:|:-----------:|
|   a1   |  9   |  9   |  9   |  2018/06/01 |
|   a1   |  10  |  10  |  10  |  2017/01/01 |
|   a1   |  12  |  12  |  12  |  2020/01/01 |
```

I get rows from each table by following code:

```
select * from table2 where createDate < '2018-07-01' and mainid='a1' order by createDate desc limit 1;
select * from table3 where createDate < '2018-07-01' and mainid='a1' order by createDate desc limit 1;
select * from table4 where createDate < '2018-07-01' and mainid='a1 'order by createDate desc limit 1;

select * from table1 where id = 'a1';
```

Now I want to combine these rows with the main table's row. If there are multiple values from different tables for 1 specific column, it should use the latest row like this:

```
table1 -> colD: 1
table2 -> colB: 2
table3 -> nothing
table4 -> colA: 9, colC: 9, colE: 9

 selected row :
| id | colA | colB | colC | colD | colE |filteredDate |
|:---|:----:|:----:|:----:|:----:|:----:|:-----------:|
| a1 |  9   |  2   |  9   |  1   |  9   |  2018/07/01 |
```

How can I get this done in one query? Is this possible? Should I try it in a different way?

Comment: You should use a *sql join* for this kind of scenarios

Comment: It would make it sooo much easier for us if you provided a fiddle or actual `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements. And always your version of Postgres, of course.

Comment: Sorry, I will take care of it on the future. :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all columns to be `NOT NULL` or you'll have to do more.

For a start you can `UNION ALL` the queries you listed and fill in NULL values for missing columns to arrive at a compatible row type. Then aggregate. The remaining difficulty is that the perfect aggregate function for the task is not implemented in stock Postgres ...

#### With standard, stock SQL tools

```
SELECT id
    , (array_agg(colA ORDER BY colA IS NULL, createDate DESC))[1] AS colA
    , (array_agg(colB ORDER BY colB IS NULL, createDate DESC))[1] AS colB
    , (array_agg(colC ORDER BY colC IS NULL, createDate DESC))[1] AS colC
    , (array_agg(colD ORDER BY colD IS NULL, createDate DESC))[1] AS colD
    , (array_agg(colE ORDER BY colE IS NULL, createDate DESC))[1] AS colE
FROM (
   select      id, colA, colB, colC, colD, colE, createDate from table1 where id = 'a1'
   UNION ALL
   (select mainid, colA, colB, NULL, NULL, NULL, createDate from table2 where createDate < '2018-07-01' and mainid='a1' order by createDate desc limit 1)
   UNION ALL
   (select mainid, colA, colB, colC, NULL, NULL, createDate from table3 where createDate < '2018-07-01' and mainid='a1' order by createDate desc limit 1)
   UNION ALL
   (select mainid, colA, NULL, colc, NULL, colE, createDate from table4 where createDate < '2018-07-01' and mainid='a1' order by createDate desc limit 1)
   ) sub
GROUP BY 1;
```

#### With custom aggregate function `first()`

Simpler and faster with the help of a custom aggregate function like instructed in the Postgres Wiki [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate)):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION first_agg ( anyelement, anyelement )
RETURNS anyelement LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT AS 'SELECT $1';
 
CREATE AGGREGATE FIRST (
        sfunc    = first_agg,
        basetype = anyelement,
        stype    = anyelement
);
```

Then:

```
SELECT id
     , first(colA) AS colA
     , first(colB) AS colB
     , first(colC) AS colC
     , first(colD) AS colD
     , first(colE) AS colE
FROM (
   SELECT      id, colA, colB, colC, colD, colE, createDate FROM table1 WHERE     id='a1'
   UNION ALL
   (SELECT mainid, colA, colB, NULL, NULL, NULL, createDate FROM table2 WHERE mainid='a1' AND createDate < '2018-07-01' ORDER BY createDate DESC LIMIT 1)
   UNION ALL
   (SELECT mainid, colA, colB, colC, NULL, NULL, createDate FROM table3 WHERE mainid='a1' AND createDate < '2018-07-01' ORDER BY createDate DESC LIMIT 1)
   UNION ALL
   (SELECT mainid, colA, NULL, colc, NULL, colE, createDate FROM table4 WHERE mainid='a1' AND createDate < '2018-07-01' ORDER BY createDate DESC LIMIT 1)
   ORDER BY createDate DESC
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Faster yet with a C implementation as provided by [this additional module](https://pgxn.org/dist/first_last_agg/).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=39b0a9405a0ab45171f0f506031aed60)*

Related, with more details and options:

- [Use something like TOP with GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934741/use-something-like-top-with-group-by/43937668#43937668)

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me a lot. I don't know what to say you are amazing!

Answer (score 0):

first_value from [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) also works.

```
select distinct on(1) id,
       first_value(cola) over 
           (partition by id order by cola is null, createDate desc) cola_firstvalue,
       first_value(colb) over
           (partition by id order by colb is null, createDate desc) colb_firstvalue,
       first_value(colc) over
           (partition by id order by colc is null, createDate desc) colc_firstvalue,
       first_value(cold) over 
           (partition by id order by cold is null, createDate desc) cold_firstvalue,
       first_value(cole) over 
           (partition by id order by cole is null, createDate desc) cole_firstvalue
from
(select id, cola, colb, colc, cold, cole, createDate 
    from table1 where id = 'a1'
union all
select mainid, cola, colb, null,null,null,createdate 
    from table2 where mainid = 'a1' and createdate < '2018-07-01'
union all
select mainid, cola, colb, colc, null,null, createDate 
    from table3 where mainid = 'a1' and createdate < '2018-07-01'
union all
select mainid, cola, null, colc, null, cole, createdate 
    from table4 where mainid = 'a1' and createdate < '2018-07-01')
sub;
```